# JQuery slide.Toggle menu firefox problem

Tags: jquery

Well, take a look at www.creade.biz

Now click o A4 ITEM and JQuery to see slideToggle in action.
It works fine in IE but crash in Firefox. If you try to close the opene A4 ITEM It will reopen.
How I can fix It?

Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your XHTML document has a whole bunch of validation errors:

- Using a `<div>` tag as a direct child of a `<ul>` tag.
- Using `<li>` tags without a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) tag as its direct parent.
- Using `<p>` tags as children for `<span>` tags.

If you change `<div class="collSub">` into `<li class="collSub">`, start a new `<ul>` tag for the nested list elements under the A4 item, and change all of your `<p>` tags into `<span>` tags, it'll work out for you.

Also, for future reference, you can check the markup validity of your XHTML documents by using [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Thanx a lot Tinister! You're a guru!